# Sencha Touch 2 - Slide Animation on button

Tags: animation, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to get a slide animation on a button inside a container but I'm unable to do it.

By the way, *fade* and *flip* was working fine.

I want to do animation like shown below when all buttons are shown.

Here's the image of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: http://oi47.tinypic.com/r9o8w7.jpg]

**EDIT :**

I am running the below code inside `initialize()` event of the container.

```
 Ext.Anim.run(this.getComponent('btnId'),'flip',{
            out: true,
            delay: 1000,
            duration: 500,
 });
```

Comment: Could you post the code of what worked (flip and fade) and what didn't (slide apparently). It would be easier to take it from here.

Comment: @TDeBailleul : I have posted the code. Can you please help me now ... flip is working fine on android, but if i choose `slide` animation, it  doesn't work ...

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.Anim.run(Ext.getCmp('btnId'), 'slide', {
    direction: 'left',
    duration: 1000
})
```

But the important thing is to ensure you require `Ext.Anim` in your application. Put this in your main app.js

```
Ext.requires('Ext.Anim');
```

or

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'myapp',
    requires: [
         'Ext.Anim'
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @user1452041 try this please,

```
Ext.Anim.run(Ext.getCmp('btnId'), 'slide', {
    direction: 'left'
})
```

`direction` attribute depend you if you want to `left` or `right`

I hope this helps. :) Ciao